# Convert RotationMatrix to RotationTransform

Tags: conversion, coordinate-transformation

Is it possible to convert `RotationMatrix` to `RotationTransform` ?
I guess it should exist a function to do this

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 7):

One only needs to apply `AffineTransform[]` to the result of `RotationMatrix[]`; e.g.

```
AffineTransform[RotationMatrix[π/3, Normalize[{1, 2, 3}]]] ===
RotationTransform[π/3, Normalize[{1, 2, 3}]]
   True
```

An additional advantage to using `AffineTransform[]` is that one can put in other classes of rotation matrices, instead of just `RotationMatrix[]`; e.g. `AffineTransform[RollPitchYawMatrix[{-π/4, π/6, 3 π/5}]]` or `AffineTransform[EulerMatrix[{π/2, -π/5, 2 π/3}]]`.

Comment: TransformtionFunction works the same: 'TransformationFunction[
  RotationMatrix[\[Pi]/3, Normalize[{0, 0, 1}]]] == 
 RotationTransform[Pi/3]'

Comment: @bill, since `TransformationFunction[]` takes a homogeneous transformation matrix as an argument, in general one needs to augment the starting matrix beforehand.

Comment: The role of the Normalize[0,0,1] is exactly the augmentation, just as with AffineTransform

Comment: Right; `RotationMatrix[π/3, Normalize[{0, 0, 1}]` effectively says "rotate by $\pi/3$ radians anticlockwise over the $z$-axis", which does correspond to a rotation in the $x$-$y$ plane.